# Change name of App that will appear on iPhone in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an Xcode Project called "SanchezAndTheAliensNoSpritekit". I named it like that because I had different versions of it. Now, the app is called on my phone like that swell. But if Apple will accept the app, I want the people to have it as "SanchezAndTheAliens" on their phone and not as "SanchezAndTheAliensNoSpritekit". Can I just change the name of the build?

Comment: You probably want *Sanchez And The Aliens*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to your **info.plist**
2. At the voice `Bundle display name` under `Information property list` insert **SanchezAndTheAliens**

PS: if the row doesn't exist you can add it.

[image]

Comment: that helped me! nice thank you, i will give u the green tick as it comes available :)